# How to hide Visual Studio code property name explanation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, intellisense

I want to hide the explainings of the property names inside the code line.

How can I disable this?

For example I don't want to see these:

```
name:
score:
subject:
```

inside the parenthesis.

[image: screenshot of the editor]

Comment: search settings for `hints` and disable the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Hints option should be disabled in VS Code settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).